# Mule Studio How to create global variable

Tags: mule, mule-studio

[click hear to see my flow Image](http://kongarn.com/images/mule2.png)

My test mule application.
I use curl json post data to the http-end-point and tranforms json to object and insert on my database with name (**#[message.payload.name]**)

I use catch-exception-strategy for keep error log (case Unique name)

I want to update my table with condition in field #[message.payload.name]
- mean Update mytable set Firstname = #[message.payload.name]

but in catch-exception-strategy can't access #[message.payload.name]

My configuration

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
    <data-mapper:config name="Mapper" transformationGraphPath="mapper.grf" doc:name="DataMapper"></data-mapper:config>
    <jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source1" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mule" user="root" password="1234" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source1" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"/>
    <flow name="httpPostTestFlow1" doc:name="httpPostTestFlow1"> 
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="httpPost" doc:name="httpPost"></http:inbound-endpoint>

        <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.Map"></json:json-to-object-transformer>


                <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="INSERT_TOKEN"  connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
                    <jdbc-ee:query key="INSERT_TOKEN" value="insert into users(FirstName) values(#[message.payload.name]);"/>
                </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>


              <!--  <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="80" path="post-debug.php" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="post-debug.php"/> --> 


         <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <expression-component doc:name="Create error response">#[message.payload = "{\"status\":\"error\", \"message\":\"" + exception.cause.message + "\"}"]</expression-component>
            <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"   connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database" queryTimeout="-1" queryKey="UPDATE_TOKEN">
                    <jdbc-ee:query key="UPDATE_TOKEN" value="update users SET fail_message = #[message.payload]"/>
                </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
        </catch-exception-strategy>


    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the title you want to have a some sort of global variable, one way is you can try using flowVars as a quick fix. Using Mule Studio it is the same as Variable (under Transformers).

The message you get inside the catch exception strategy is the exception.

Comment: less of document , Thank you so much